# Empty #define in .vsarduino.h (Visual Micro)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, arduino

I'm using Visual Micro to write code for an Arduino (Nano in this case) in Visual Studio 2012. I have a compile error in the generated `.vsarduino.h` file, an empty `#define` is being generated and I'm not sure where it is coming from:

**.vsarduino.h**

```
#ifndef _VSARDUINO_H_
#define _VSARDUINO_H_
//Board = Arduino Nano w/ ATmega328
#define __AVR_ATmega328P__
#define 
#define _VMDEBUG 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry we missed this question. Hopefully it was answered in the Visual Micro [forum](http://www.visualmicro.com/forums).

The vsarduino.h is not included in the compile and is only used for Visual Studio intellisense.

Only real Arduino source is compiled by Visual Micro which means the sketch remains compatible with the Arduino IDE

Thanks