# Is there a pratical reason for defining a uint8_t as unsigned short?

Tags: c++, arduino

Creating an Arduino project in Visual studio, a project file named .*nameProject*.vsarduino.h is automatically created, in which the following lines define the uint8_t and int8_t type:

```
typedef unsigned short uint8_t;
typedef short int8_t;
```

I've seen that uint8_t is in fact a type that contains *at least* 8 bits.

I wonder if this definition could bring a lot of mistakes, for example managing streams of bytes used for i2c communication for which the field lengths are typically defined in terms of bytes.

Many library functions, in fact, use indifferently uint8_t or unsigned char, but in this practical case this is not the same type.

Any comment and/or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer tells us, that uintxx_t will have *exactly* xx bits. If thats the case, it is a good idea to use a data type where we know what we have instead of the good old c style types which have always "a minimum size". On small bare metal embedded systems, every bit counts...

Comment: `uint8_t` has exactly 8 bits by the standard, no more, no less.

Comment: This is non-conforming.  [Per the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/tab:basic.fundamental.width) `short` must be at least 16 bits wide.

Comment: `uint8_t` and `int8_t`, if supported, are required to have exactly 8 bits.  `unsigned short` and `short` are specified as having at least 16 bits.   This means the generated header is non-conforming.   You'll need to read documentation for arduino projects under VS to understand any practical implications of this non-compliance for your projects.

Comment: What compiler is Visual Studio using to compile the Arduino project? This may be an attempt to fix broken compiler.

Comment: If there's a compiler that broken, there must surely be a better alternative. Correctly-sized fixed-width (and short) types seem like a very basic requirement for an embedded cross-compiler.

Comment: "The vsarduino.h is not included in the compile and is only used for Visual Studio intellisense." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558831/empty-define-in-vsarduino-h-visual-micro

Comment: Guys, don't blame me. I'm just trying to understand why there is this definition. I agree with all of you that this is nonsense, I know very well that a uint8_t has 8bits, it's the reason why I'm writing here. I'm using Visual Studio as IDE, with the VisualMicro Arduino IDE and the Teensyduino add-on. I don't know who is responsible for this definition, I'm asking to the expert here if there is a practical reason for this.

Answer (score 4):

> I've seen that uint8_t is in fact a type that contains at least 8 bits.

Where? The fixed width types in [`<cstdint>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint) are provided specifically to expose types whose width is fixed at *exactly* the number of bits mentioned in the type name. Not *bounded below*. So `uint8_t` must have exactly 8 bits.

If you just want an unsigned type whose width is *at least* 8 bits, use `unsigned char`.

> Many library functions, in fact, use indifferently uint8_t or unsigned char, but in this practical case this is not the same type.

This is fine for a platform-specific library that knows its platform's `unsigned char` is exactly 8 bits, and then it *is* the same type.

This, on the other hand:

```
typedef unsigned short uint8_t;
```

is always guaranteed to be wrong. Both `short` and `unsigned short` are required to be *at least* 16 bits.

If the platform can't expose a type with *exactly* 8 bits, it shouldn't provide an 8-bit fixed-width type at all.

Comment: Well, it is just a comment in the arduino forum, then it's maybe not a trustable source:
https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=206959.msg1522260#msg1522260. I cite here: 

"uint8_t, is a standard name that is defined in the stdint.h header file for an unsigned integer that is at least 8 bits in size, while byte is defined in the Arduino headers"

Comment: Yep, that particular part of that post is just wrong. Replace _at least_ with _exactly_ and it's correct, though, and I think the rest of the post looks reasonable as well.